# Reposition Text around Images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

So I'm trying to work on a visual layout for a kind of Xmas card. The idea is to have a pictures in the upper left and lower right corners with the family name and date centered in the upper right quadrant. I can get the text centered horizontally, but it lines up with the bottom of the top left image (right above the bottom right image). If anyone could help me move it so the text is on a line going through the center of the top image that would be great:

```
\includegraphics[scale = 0.15]{Family.jpg} \hspace{\fill\textbf{\textsc{\Large{FamilyNameHere\\Date}}}\hspace*{\fill}
\newline
\hspace*{\fill}\includegraphics[scale = 0.05]{Family2.jpg}
```

Answer (score 5):

Centred vertical alignment of graphics is easily obtained with the help of [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox), which provides the `valign` key-value option. Below is a minimal example showing its use in your case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}% adjustbox loads graphicx
\begin{document}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}%
\hfill
{\Large\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{c}
  Family Name Here \\
  Date
\end{tabular}}\hspace*{\fill}

\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}

\end{document}
```

I've used a `tabular` to structure the family name and date, since the default vertical alignment is centred.

Loading `adjustbox` with the `[export]` option makes its keys available to the [`graphicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `tikz` solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=0.5\textwidth] (a)
       {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \node[outer sep=0pt,text width=0.5\textwidth,align=center,anchor=west]
        at (a.east) {Family Name Here \\
                             Date};
  \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=0.5\textwidth,anchor=north west]
        at (a.south east) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution without additional packages is split your card in four `minipage`s. By default the minipages are centered vertically, so this work to center images and/or anything else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\Img#1{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-#1}}
\def\Family{\centering\Large\textsc{Family Name Here}\\[1em]\textit\today} 
\begin{document}
\parindent0pt
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} \Img{a} \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} \Family \end{minipage}\\[-1pt]
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} ~ \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth} \Img{c} \end{minipage}\par
\end{document}
```

Obviously, the empty minipage in this case could be safely replaced by `\raggedleft` or anything else to align the last minipage to the right, but may be you want add here some text or decoration.
[image: MWE]